# Internal Server Error 500 on AWS after deploying Django app - following the AWS tutorial

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services

I am trying to learn how to deploy Django/Python to AWS.  I have been using the [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html#python-django-deploy).

I have followed it (I believe) pretty much to the letter except that I am using pipenv shell as the virtual environment.

Here is the django.config file:

```
option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: ebdjango/wsgi.py
```

I updated the ALLOWED HOSTS file:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['django-env.kdkep9ewpv.eu-west-2.elasticbeanstalk.com']
```

Here is the wsgi file:

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'ebdjango.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

And the error logs are below:

```
[Sat Oct 12 10:23:29.570668 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 3119] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sat Oct 12 10:23:29.586082 2019] [http2:warn] [pid 3119] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Sat Oct 12 10:23:29.586092 2019] [http2:warn] [pid 3119] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Sat Oct 12 10:23:29.586517 2019] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 3119] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sat Oct 12 10:23:29.586560 2019] [:warn] [pid 3119] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.6.2.
[Sat Oct 12 10:23:29.586563 2019] [:warn] [pid 3119] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.6.8.
[Sat Oct 12 10:23:29.588473 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3119] AH00163: Apache/2.4.39 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Oct 12 10:23:29.588490 2019] [core:notice] [pid 3119] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:07.484783 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3119] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:08.538325 2019] [suexec:notice] [pid 3337] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:08.553978 2019] [so:warn] [pid 3337] AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:08.556110 2019] [http2:warn] [pid 3337] AH10034: The mpm module (prefork.c) is not supported by mod_http2. The mpm determines how things are processed in your server. HTTP/2 has more demands in this regard and the currently selected mpm will just not do. This is an advisory warning. Your server will continue to work, but the HTTP/2 protocol will be inactive.
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:08.556120 2019] [http2:warn] [pid 3337] AH02951: mod_ssl does not seem to be enabled
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:08.556651 2019] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 3337] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:08.556714 2019] [:warn] [pid 3337] mod_wsgi: Compiled for Python/3.6.2.
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:08.556720 2019] [:warn] [pid 3337] mod_wsgi: Runtime using Python/3.6.8.
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:08.559127 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 3337] AH00163: Apache/2.4.39 (Amazon) mod_wsgi/3.5 Python/3.6.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:08.559143 2019] [core:notice] [pid 3337] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.617103 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=3342): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/ebdjango/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.617157 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] mod_wsgi (pid=3342): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/ebdjango/wsgi.py'.
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619206 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619288 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/current/app/ebdjango/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619294 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619300 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619304 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619310 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619313 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619319 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619329 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     app_config.import_models()
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619335 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619338 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619343 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619346 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619351 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619356 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619362 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619367 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619372 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619377 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619385 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py", line 2, in <module>
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619388 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619394 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619397 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619402 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 117, in __new__
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619405 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619409 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619412 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619418 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619421 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619426 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619429 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619434 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619437 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619442 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619445 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619453 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619456 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619461 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 66, in <module>
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619465 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     check_sqlite_version()
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619470 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 63, in check_sqlite_version
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619473 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0]     raise ImproperlyConfigured('SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found %s).' % Database.sqlite_version)
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:11.619489 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:0] django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: SQLite 3.8.3 or later is required (found 3.7.17).
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:12.622906 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160] mod_wsgi (pid=3342): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/ebdjango/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:12.622962 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160] mod_wsgi (pid=3342): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/ebdjango/wsgi.py'.
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:12.623076 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:12.623110 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]   File "/opt/python/current/app/ebdjango/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:12.623114 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:12.623121 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:12.623124 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:12.623130 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:12.623133 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:12.623139 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 83, in populate
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:12.623143 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:12.623158 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:13.626532 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160] mod_wsgi (pid=3342): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/ebdjango/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:13.626579 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160] mod_wsgi (pid=3342): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/ebdjango/wsgi.py'.
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:13.626686 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:13.626726 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]   File "/opt/python/current/app/ebdjango/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:13.626731 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:13.626737 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:13.626740 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:13.626756 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:13.626759 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:13.626765 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 83, in populate
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:13.626768 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:13.626783 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:160] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:14.629908 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:164] mod_wsgi (pid=3342): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/ebdjango/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:14.629957 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:164] mod_wsgi (pid=3342): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/ebdjango/wsgi.py'.
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:14.630065 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:164] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:14.630097 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:164]   File "/opt/python/current/app/ebdjango/wsgi.py", line 16, in <module>
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:14.630102 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:164]     application = get_wsgi_application()
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:14.630108 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:164]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/wsgi.py", line 12, in get_wsgi_application
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:14.630111 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:164]     django.setup(set_prefix=False)
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:14.630117 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:164]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:14.630120 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:164]     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:14.630126 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:164]   File "/opt/python/run/venv/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 83, in populate
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:14.630129 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:164]     raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
[Sat Oct 12 10:24:14.630144 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 127.0.0.1:164] RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
[Sat Oct 12 10:26:42.457985 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 172.31.41.246:164] mod_wsgi (pid=3342): Target WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/ebdjango/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat Oct 12 10:26:42.458040 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 172.31.41.246:164] mod_wsgi (pid=3342): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/opt/python/current/app/ebdjango/wsgi.py'.
[Sat Oct 12 10:26:42.458150 2019] [:error] [pid 3342] [remote 172.31.41.246:164] Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Where am I going wrong?